# 'angular' is not defined while using Codekit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codekit

CodeKit keeps giving me a warning every time I save `myApp.js`.  When I load index.html via the CodeKit preview the `firstName` and `lastName` variables appear fine.  I just want this issue to go away.

```
"var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
'angular' is not defined"
```

Here are my two files `index.html` and `myApp.js`

index.html:

```
<html>
<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="myApp.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

myApp.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName    = "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting ng-app="myApp" in the <html> tag?

Comment: it's nothing to do with ng-app @RenanLopesFerreira

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira yes I just tried that and I am still getting the warning.

Comment: Have you checked the path to `angular.js`?

Comment: Is `<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>` ok ? i mean is there a file name `angular.js` in `angular` folder which location in root folder of .html page ?

Comment: I believe that angular/angular.js is working properly because the data binding is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried Claies' solution, but what we do in our project is simply register it as a global so that Codekit does not complain. Only do this if you are sure you have angular defined, else it will hide errors.

**Option 1 - for jshint**

Put the following in your JS file:

```
/*global angular:true */
```

*Reference: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#jshint*

**Option 2 - for both jshint and jslint**

Alternatively, you can define your globals in the Codekit config:

1. Within Codekit, open 'Project Settings'
2. Choose 'Syntax Checkers'
3. In the 'Custom Globals' textfield you can enter a list of comma separated variables and functions that you know are defined elsewhere outside your JS
   script.

*Reference: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#jslint*

Comment: FYI, I know this is from 3 years ago, but yet I still came across this on Google and felt it needed additional options/further explanation for anyone else coming across it. Else they would think the reference path answer by Claies is the only option. Always best to present multiple options/routes.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring due to the Code Linting process which is actively searching for syntax errors.  Unfortunately, it doesn't realize that `angular` is a global variable which is available to *your* script file, because it is declared in a different file.  It actually works in the browser (or the preview pane) but the Linting isn't aware of the existence of `angular`.

you can add `/// <reference path="angular/angular.js" />` at the top of your JavaScript files to inform the syntax checker where the `angular` variable is actually declared.